# paperjs: stroke with gradient

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

I want to draw a graph (a line) which is blue when the values are 0 and gets more red when the values are ~100 (so the color of the line has to be a gradient).

I 've got two ideas that might work, but maybe there is a better solution out there.

1. Don't draw a line, but multiple circles every pixel and color those circles based on its x-value.
2. Place the gradient in the background and use the line as a clipping mask. Is that possible in paperjs and if yes how?

Although idea 1. is pretty easy to implement I don't think that I will get a smooth result.

I would be very grateful if could give me a better approach or a example how I can use a line as a clipping mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below. Play around with values to get the result you exactly want. The below code will help you understand how to apply gradient to a line.

```
// Define two points which we will be using to construct
// the path and to position the gradient color:
var point1 = [0,350];
var point2 = [350, 0];

// Create a line between point1 and point2 points:
var path = new Path.Line({
    from: point1,
    to: point2,
    // Fill the line stroke with a gradient of two color stops
    strokeColor: {
    gradient: {
        stops: ['blue', 'red']
    },
            //origin and destination defines the direction of your gradient. In this case its vertical i.e bottom(blue/cooler) to up(red/warmer) refering to link you sent.
    origin: [0,200], //gradient will start applying from y=200 towards y=0. Adjust this value to get your desired result
    destination: [0,0]
},
    strokeWidth: 5
});
```

Hope this makes things a bit easier for you.

Note:
You can also change the percentage of blue and red in the gradient given above like this:

```
...
gradient: {
    // blue from 0% to 33%, mix between blue and red from 33% to 66%, and remaining red (66% to 100%)
    // mix between red and black from 20% to 100%:
    stops: [['blue',0.33], ['red',0.66]]
},
origin: [0,350],
destination: [0,0],
...
```

Comment: This doesn't consider the x-value of the curve. Or did I miss something? I want something like this: http://classwarinamerica.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/1-global_temp.jpg

Comment: I have made changes as per you requirements. Hope this brings you more closer towards solving your issue. Please +1 if it was helpful ;)

Comment: Sorry, your first and your second solution work perfect.

Comment: @sohel: Here is your example translated as http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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